# selenium 4 parallel run exception org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid, gauge

I am getting exception for gauge parallel running for new selenium 4 docker grid images (selenium/node-chrome:4.3.0-20220706, image: selenium/hub:4.3.0-20220706)

Exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.makeCall(NettyHttpHandler.java:65)
org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AddSeleniumUserAgent.lambda$apply$0(AddSeleniumUserAgent.java:42)
org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter.lambda$andFinally$1(Filter.java:56)
org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.execute(NettyHttpHandler.java:49)
org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AddSeleniumUserAgent.lambda$apply$0(AddSeleniumUserAgent.java:42)
org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter.lambda$andFinally$1(Filter.java:56)
org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.execute(NettyClient.java:98)
org.openqa.selenium.remote.tracing.TracedHttpClient.execute(TracedHttpClient.java:55)
org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:181)
org.openqa.selenium.remote.TracedCommandExecutor.execute(TracedCommandExecutor.java:51)
org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:569)
org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:257)
org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:78)
com.norvax.specifications.utils.elements.ElementAction.checkOrUncheckCheckbox(ElementAction.kt:118)
com.norvax.specifications.affiliatesmanagement.AffiliatesManagement.selectAffiliate(AffiliatesManagement.kt:797)
com.norvax.specifications.affiliatesmanagement.AffiliatesManagement.selectAffiliateFromReport(AffiliatesManagement.kt:242)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
com.thoughtworks.gauge.execution.MethodExecutor.execute(MethodExecutor.java:28)
com.thoughtworks.gauge.execution.StepExecutionStage.executeStepMethod(StepExecutionStage.java:66)
com.thoughtworks.gauge.execution.StepExecutionStage.executeStep(StepExecutionStage.java:59)
com.thoughtworks.gauge.execution.StepExecutionStage.execute(StepExecutionStage.java:41)
com.thoughtworks.gauge.execution.AbstractExecutionStage.executeNext(AbstractExecutionStage.java:14)
com.thoughtworks.gauge.execution.HookExecutionStage.execute(HookExecutionStage.java:33)
com.thoughtworks.gauge.execution.ExecutionPipeline.start(ExecutionPipeline.java:19)
com.thoughtworks.gauge.processor.ExecuteStepProcessor.process(ExecuteStepProcessor.java:44)
com.thoughtworks.gauge.RunnerServiceHandler.lambda$executeStep$7(RunnerServiceHandler.java:166)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

It is occurring randomly on different actions(clic, findElement, switch) in different scenarios each run.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a known issue reported here:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/9528

So far, no solution has been found except maybe switching from Docker to another driver for browsers.